# can't figure out how to create source folders on eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm having a problem on making a path on eclipse.

/chap02/src/main/java/chap02/CalculatorTest.java
/chap02/src/test/java/chap02/Calculator.java

/chap02/ is a java project
/src/test/java is a source folder
and chap02 is a package(not sure).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNZOJ.png)

b

I tried to make source folders on src.
but I error on image is keep occuring.

Comment: You probably need to delete the existing 'src' entry before trying to add the new source folder.